# SQLiteOpenHelper multiple in-memory databases

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

[`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) provides the ability to use an in-memory database if the name argument to its constructor is `null`:

> String: of the database file, or null for an in-memory database

If `SQLiteOpenHelper` is instantiated multiple times with a `null` name argument, do they access the same in-memory database or is a separate in-memory database created each time?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Considering the fact that you added an elaborated answer, I think it would be better to remove this misguiding comment now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From SQLite official documentation **[In-Memory Databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)**

**Opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.**

In Android, pass null instead of ":memory:"

So, If you instantiate SQLiteOpenHelper multiple times with a null name argument then it create separate in-memory database created each time

Comment: See @cricket_007's answer for more details since that got posted while I was researching this.  `SQLiteDatabaseConfiguration.MEMORY_DB_PATH = ":memory:"` which is referenced from `SQLiteDatabase.create` to create a memory backed database.  This passes through to `openDatabase` which instantiates `SQLiteDatabase` with the `":memory:"` path.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java), we see that in the constructor `mName` would get set to `null`.

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version,
        DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    if (version < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be >= 1, was " + version);

    mContext = context;
    mName = name;
    mFactory = factory;
    mNewVersion = version;
    mErrorHandler = errorHandler;
}
```

Which means `getDatabaseName()` returns `null`.

```
public String getDatabaseName() {
    return mName;
}
```

Later, through the use of `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`, if `mName` is `null`, then it calls the `create` method for an in-memory database instead of trying to opening one from disk.

```
if (mName == null) {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.create(null); // in-memory
} else {
    // db file opened or created
}
... 
return db;
```

That `db` variable is maintained in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` until it is closed, which in the case of an in-memory database, means the data is deleted.

---

To clarify,

Each instance of a `SQLiteOpenHelper` that uses an in-memory database will its own database while the same instance will use one database and persist that data until it is closed.

Comment: Thanks for researching the source.  Combined with @USKMobility's answer, it looks like calls to the same `SQLiteOpenHelper` would yield the same database (assuming it hasn't been closed) and calls to different instances of `SQLiteOpenHelper` would create and access separate in memory databases.